# Tic Tac Toe board printing incorrectly in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a tic-tac-toe game in Java and the first step I do is make the board.

The board is supposed to be 3x3 because of the loops. Can anyone help me out? Here is the code:

```
package myProject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacDoe {

    public static int row,col;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    public static char turn = 'X';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++){
                board[i][j] = '_';
            }
            PrintBoard();
        }

    }

    public static void Play() {

    }

    public static void PrintBoard() {
        for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++) {
                if(j==0)
                    System.out.println("| ");
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean GameOver(int rMove, int cMove) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you just want your `println("| ")` to be `print("| ")`

Comment: It looks better now, but it is way too long . It's like 5x3 not 3x3

Comment: Try moving your `Printboard()` method call out of the `for (int i = ...)` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToe {

    public static int row,col;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    public static char turn = 'X';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++){
                board[i][j] = '_';
            }

        }
        PrintBoard();
    }

    public static void Play() {

    }

    public static void PrintBoard() {
        for(int i = 0;i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for(int j = 0;j < 3;j++) {
                if(j==0)
                    System.out.print("| ");
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean GameOver(int rMove, int cMove) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Moves the PrintBoard() out of the nested for loop, and changed the if(j==0) to System.out.print

Gives the output

```
| _ | _ | _ | 
| _ | _ | _ | 
| _ | _ | _ |
```